# When is Rabin Karp more effective than KMP or Boyer-Moore?

Tags: string-search, knuth-morris-pratt, rabin-karp, boyer-moore

I'm learning about string searching algorithms and understand how they work but haven't found a good enough answer about in which cases Rabin-Karp algorithm would be more effective than KMP or Boyer-Moore. I see that it is easier to implement and doesn't need the same overhead but beyond that, I have no clue.

So, when is Rabin-Karp better to use than the others?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are a couple of properties that each of these algorithms have that might make them desirable or undesirable in different circumstances. Here's a quick rundown:

### Space Usage favors Rabin-Karp

One major advantage of Rabin-Karp is that it uses O(1) auxiliary storage space, which is great if the pattern string you're looking for is very large. For example, if you're looking for all occurrences of a string of length 10<sup>7</sup> in a longer string of length 10<sup>9</sup>, not having to allocate a table of 10<sup>7</sup> machine words for a failure function or shift table is a major win. Both Boyer-Moore and KMP use Ω(n) memory on a pattern string of length n, so Rabin-Karp would be a clear win here.

### Worst-Case Single-Match Efficiency Favors Boyer-Moore or KMP

Rabin-Karp suffers from two potential worst cases. First, if the particular prime numbers used by Rabin-Karp are known to a malicious adversary, that adversary could potentially craft an input that causes the rolling hash to match the hash of a pattern string at each point in time, causing the algorithm's performance to degrade to Ω((m - n + 1)n) on a string of length m and pattern of length n. If you're taking untrusted strings as input, this could potentially be an issue. Neither Boyer-Moore nor KMP have these weaknesses.

### Worst-Case Multiple-Match Efficiency favors KMP.

Similarly, Rabin-Karp is slow in the case where you want to find all matches of a pattern string in the case where that pattern appears a large number of times. For example, if you're looking for a string of 10<sup>5</sup> copies of the letter `a` in text string consisting of 10<sup>9</sup>copies of the letter `a` with Rabin-Karp, then there will be lots of spots where the pattern string appears, and each will require a linear scan. This can also lead to a runtime of Ω((m + n - 1)n).

Many Boyer-Moore implementations suffer from this second rule, but will not have bad runtimes in the first case. And KMP has no pathological worst-cases like these.

### Best-Case Performance favors Boyer-Moore

One advantage of the Boyer-Moore algorithm is that it doesn't necessarily have to scan all the characters of the input string. Specifically, the Bad Character Rule can be used to skip over huge regions of the input string in the event of a mismatch. More specifically, the best-case runtime for Boyer-Moore is O(m / n), which is much faster than what Rabin-Karp or KMP can provide.

### Generalizations to Multiple Strings favor KMP

Suppose you have a fixed set of multiple text strings that you want to search for, rather than just one. You could, if you wanted to, run multiple passes of Rabin-Karp, KMP, or Boyer-Moore across the strings to find all the matches. However, the runtime of this approach isn't great, as it scales linearly with the number of strings to search for. On the other hand, KMP generalizes nicely to the Aho-Corasick string-matching algorithm, which runs in time O(m + n + z), where z is the number of matches found and n is the combined length of the pattern strings. Notice that there's no dependence here on the number of different pattern strings being searched for!

Comment: One more thing regarding your last heading "Generalization to multiple strings": If each pattern in our set of patterns that we are looking for has the same length m, Rabin Karp has O(n + km) complexity

Answer (score 4):

The **Rabin-Karp** algorithm is better when searching for a large text that is finding multiple pattern matches, like detecting plagiarism.

And **Boyer-Moore** is better when the pattern is relatively large with a moderately sized alphabet and with a large vocabulary. And it does not work well with binary strings or very short patterns.

Meanwhile, **KMP** is good for searching inside a smaller alphabet, like in bioinformatics or searching in binary strings. And it does not run fast if the alphabet increases.

Comment: Why KMP does not run fast if the alphabet increases? I've never seen this lemma explained.

Comment: KMP visits every character exactly once (linear runtime), Boyer-Moore can skip character sequences (sublinear runtime). The skipping of character sequences depends on a mismatch at the end of the pattern, which is more probable with larger alphabets.

Answer (score 1):

Space-Time complexities of all three (for reference)
(For finding ALL occurrences of the pattern)

m : length of the pattern

n : length of the String in which we search the pattern

k : size of the alphabet

**Rabin Karp:**

O(1) auxiliary space

Uses hashing to find an exact match of a pattern string in a text. It uses a rolling hash to quickly filter out positions of the text that cannot match the pattern, and then checks for a match at the remaining positions

**Boyer Moore:**

Worst-case performance  : Θ(m) preprocessing + O(mn) matching

Best-case performance   : Θ(m) preprocessing + Ω(n/m) matching

Worst-case space complexity : Θ(k).

Can be used for "grep" like searches.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm#Performance

**Knuth Morris Pratt:**

Worst-case performance  : Θ(m) preprocessing + Θ(n) matching

Worst-case space complexity : Θ(m)

For more details lookup in Wikipedia for each algorithm.